# How to parse XML in a table returned from server

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

Return data from an ajax POST form is a table. Table has xml in one cell, I can get to the necessary cell and display it on the page as either straight xml with all tags present or just display the text. I need to format the xml somehow, currently the only affect I'm having on it is when its straight xml and styled with css - this is not desirable.

```
success: function(data) {
    var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").html();
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( message );
    var $xml = $( xmlDoc );
if (answer==="True") {
    $xml.each(function() {
       $('#resultGenerate').show().append($(this).html());
});
} else {
    $('.processing').hide();
    $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
    $('#resultGenerate').show().html('<ul><li>' + answer + '</li><li>' + message +    
    '</ul>');
}
}
```

The above just returns it as text, how do I parse the xml to grab the tags and append them in a table? Ive been at this all day, I really need some help. I know I need to set a var for each xml tag such as

```
var xmltagfoo = $(this).find('xmltagfoo').text();
```

and then append like so

```
$('#resultGenerate').append($('<td>' + xmltagfoo + '</td>'));
```

but I simply cannot get this to work. please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this to work, it's easy to do with a GET request, but when data is returned from a POST, its a little trickier. Here's how I did it

```
$.ajax({
type: $(form).attr('method'),
url: form.action,
data: dataString,
clearForm: true,
success: function(data) {
    var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
    var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").html();
    var $xml = $( message );

    if (answer==="True") {
        $xml.find('license').each(function(){
    var XXXCustomerID = $(this).find(XXXCustomerID').text();
            var XXLicense  = $(this).find('XXLicense').text();
            var Log  = $(this).find('Log').text();
            var ExpirationDate  = $(this).find('ExpirationDate').text();
    $("#resultGenerate").show().append($('<li><span class="ID">' + XXXCustomerID + '</span><span class="NTL">' + XXLicense + '</span><span class="Log">' + Log + '</span><span class="Exp">' + ExpirationDate + '</span></li>'));
            });
    } else {
            $('.processing').hide();
            $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
            }
        }
    });
```